# AS3 - Why is the font being cleared after setting text of a TextField?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, textfield

I have the following setup: In Label.fla there is a MovieClip that contains a TextField, which has its class set to src.components.Label. All this class does is set the font in the constructor and then set the text property of the TextField to an empty string (the value of the string doesn't matter for this problem. It can be a non-empty string and have the same result). Like this:

```
package src.components
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Label extends MovieClip
    {
        public var mTextField:TextField;

        public function Label()
        {
            super();

            var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 34, 0xFFFFFF);
            mTextField.defaultTextFormat = tf;
            mTextField.setTextFormat(tf);

            trace("init before: " + mTextField.getTextFormat().font);
            mTextField.text = "";
            trace("init after: " + mTextField.getTextFormat().font);
        }
    }
}
```

The label object in Label.fla is set up to export for runtime sharing, which has been copied into MainMenu.fla. A single instance of this label is placed on the stage of MainMenu.fla, and when I run MainMenu.swf the output clearly shows that the font is being set and then immediately cleared just because I'm changing the text property of the TextField.

The output looks like this:

```
init before: Arial
init after: null
```

Why would setting the text cause the font to be cleared? This is causing me a lot of problems. The only way I've figured out how to work around this is to do something stupid where I make a copy of the TextFormat object before setting the text, set the text, and then reapply the copied TextFormat to make sure it doesn't change.

I've attached a zip file containing all of the source and compiled files to test this with.
[FontTest.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/0v70419d97lw07h/FontTest.zip)

Answer (score 2):

The very short answer to the question is this:

- because you did not read the documentation.

That's right that's the only problem in your code. You are using a method (setTextFormat(tf)) that is only meant to set the format for the current existing text. This is specified in the docs of course.

The one method that sets format for any future set texts is: "defaultTextFormat". Once again this is specified in the docs and this method will not modify a text that is already set in the textfield.

So 2 methods meant for 2 different things, one (the one you use) that is used to modify the existing text, and one "defaultTextFormat" that is used to modify any future texts.

But really reading the docs would have saved you a trip to SO, read the as3 docs and answer 99% of your future questions and problems.

Comment: I don't 100% understand how defaultTextFormat works even with the documentation. I'm setting it, so I would expect that it would apply it after changing the text. Though after re-reading the docs, it only mentions using replaceSelectedText() and setSelection(), so maybe only those two functions work? I'm going to have to mess around with this more...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding off of what BotMaster posted, I reread the documentation and figured out where I was misunderstanding. You can **only** set the text using setSelection() followed by replaceSelectedText() if you want to maintain the text formatting when using defaultTextFormat. So the fixed constructor looks like this:

```
public function Label()
{
    super();

    var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 34, 0xFFFFFF);
    mTextField.defaultTextFormat = tf;

    trace("init before: " + mTextField.getTextFormat().font);
    mTextField.setSelection(0, mTextField.length);
    mTextField.replaceSelectedText("");
    trace("init after: " + mTextField.getTextFormat().font);
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
init before: Bender
init after: Arial
```

Bender is the font being set in the FLA so that is the expected starting value.

As an alternative solution, you could store the TextFormat object and just apply it after you set the text property, but I'm not sure which one is more efficient. That solution would look like this:

```
public class Label extends MovieClip
{
    public var mTextField:TextField;
    private var mTextFormat:TextFormat = null;

    public function Label()
    {
        super();

        // Storing this in a member so that anywhere in this class that you change the text
        // you can just apply it without having to reconstructing it.
        mTextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 34, 0xFFFFFF);

        trace("init before: " + mTextField.getTextFormat().font);
        mTextField.text = "";
        mTextField.setTextFormat(mTextFormat);
        trace("init after: " + mTextField.getTextFormat().font);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused... if you set `mTextField.defaultTextFormat = tf;` using Arial font, then why would it trace Bender when you do `trace("init before: "...` but anyway I think you solved a old issue for me. I always create textFields by code cos it would not update format of text if already on stage (created by "Text" icon). Looks like the working trick is `replaceSelectedText("");`. This might even be a Flash bug. I'll check things later...

Comment: It outputs Bender because setting defaultTextFormat doesn't apply the format to the existing text. It doesn't apply it until I call replaceSelectedText().

Comment: The code has been changed from the original question. using defaultTextFormat will not apply formatting to the text that was set BEFORE but will apply formatting to the text that is set AFTER, using setTextFormat works the exact opposite way.